# Gets a unreadable(i think binary) file while writing a Java Object to a text file

Tags: java, mongodb, file

How can I get a readable text file when I write a Java object to a file?

```
public void saveVehicle(){
        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("Car");

        Cursor cursor = collection.find();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("VehicleList.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                objectOut.writeObject((cursor.next()).toString());
            }
            objectOut.close();
            System.out.println("Writing to file : Successful");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error in Writing to file : " + ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: Probably by converting it to json, yaml or XML ?

Comment: @Marged uh...is YAML used as a serialization format?

Comment: @Kayaman you could use it like any of the two others. Spring uses it with `ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: @Marged sure for config, but for data exchange?

Comment: @Kayaman I would say this is a matter of personal preferences. In my opinion yaml is not much "worse" than json, it has lists and can define objects but has even less types than json. My intention was to show the OP some options, (s)he has to decide what fits here